# Show that $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x+y\neq{0}\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

I think that I have found a suitable epsilon, that is
$$\epsilon=\frac{\vert{x-y}\vert{}^2}{2}$$
but I am struggling to show that if $a\in\Omega$ and $b\in{B}(a,\epsilon)\implies{b}\in\Omega$, i.e. $b_1+b_2\neq{0}$. I just do not know what to do after noting that $b\in{B}(a,\epsilon)$.

Comment: The function $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is continuous, and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Consider the continuous map $f(x,y)=x+y$, the set $A=\{(0,0)\}$ is closed. What is the preimage of $A$ under $f$ is it closed? And what is its complement? Open?

Comment: Isn't $\epsilon=\frac{|x+y|}{\sqrt 2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=x+y$ is continuous. Furthermore the set $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, thus we get
$$f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:f(x,y)=x+y = 0\}$$
is a closed set in $\mathbb R^2$, because $f$ is continuous.
Now consider the complement of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$;
$$\mathbb R^2\setminus(f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: f(x,y)=x+y \neq 0\}=\Omega$$
this is a open set in $\mathbb R^2$ because it is the complement of a closed set.

Comment: Isn't $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$? Shouldn't it be that the point 0 is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ so $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is also closed instead?

Comment: Thanks made the edit!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a continuity argument like the one presented in the comments, you can argue as follows:

- Take an arbitrary point $\mathbf{x}=(x_0,y_0) \in \Omega$. Your goal is to find an $\epsilon$ such that the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $\mathbf{x}$ is contained entirely in $\Omega$.
- Calculate the distance $d_\mathbf{x}$ from $\mathbf{x}$ to the line $x+y=0$.
- Take $\epsilon = d_\mathbf{x}/2$ and show that $B(\mathbf{x}, \epsilon) \subseteq \Omega$. This should be obvious from the definition of $d_\mathbf{x}$.

Drawing a graph will certainly help you visualize the proof.